# Python 3.7, async/await prints in wrong order

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio

I was testing **Python3.7** async/await functions and written simple code like this:

```
import asyncio
import time


async def first():
    print('FIRST')


async def second():
    time.sleep(2)
    print('SECOND')


async def main():
    asyncio.create_task(second())
    asyncio.create_task(second())
    asyncio.create_task(second())
    asyncio.create_task(first())
    asyncio.create_task(first())
    asyncio.create_task(first())

asyncio.run(main())
```

When I run this code, it prints this:

```
SECOND
SECOND
SECOND
FIRST
FIRST
FIRST
```

Which is not what I expected. I thought `FIRST`s should be printed first because they don't have delay. However, `create_task` waits until `second()` is finished before proceeding to text async task.

Is it possible to execute async tasks without making them to wait each other?

Comment: It might be because you are using time.sleep and not asyncio.sleep

Comment: @user1558604 asyncio.sleep behaves in same way in this code

Comment: you will have to await asyncio.sleep() in case you haven't tried that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `gather()` function and modify a bit your code. You also have to use the `await` keyword.

```
import asyncio
import time


async def first():
    print('FIRST')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print('SECOND')


async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(first(), first(), first())

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: If my methods are very complex and hard to combine into one, and `second` takes more time to complete and `first` is not dependent on it? Do I need just to run each of them on separate threads instead of async?

Comment: @Mr.D `asyncio` is mostly used for connection with the server. I would recommend using the multithreading, however, it is possible to use asyncio - you have to `await` an event.

Comment: If I don't need to await their results, do I need to just use multithreading?

Comment: @Mr.D can you please upvote and accept my answer, please?

Comment: @Mr.D yes, IMO it is the best library for that.

Comment: @Mr.D You don't need to use multithreading, you can simply run each in a separate task as you have attempted already. You just need to await _something_ in `main()`, otherwise it will return immediately and cause the program to exit before it has had the chance to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the `time.sleep()` function since it is not asynchronous, resulting in an actual sleep for the entire program. use the `asyncio.sleep()` function and await it so it runs asynchronously:

```py
import asyncio


async def first():
    print('FIRST')


async def second():
    # The Fix:
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print('SECOND')


async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(
        second(),
        second(),
        second(),
        first(),
        first(),
        first()
    )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

The result should be:

```
FIRST
FIRST
FIRST
SECOND
SECOND
SECOND
```